# Modifying the table in the database without loosing the data using database first approach, Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-first

Is there a way to add/delete columns in the database using database-first approach in Entity Framework? I know we can do this by doing code-first approach.

Comment: you can do this in code-first BUT just when you upgrade your database via `Package Manager Console`. That means it happens at design time. If you mean add/remove columns of database table at runtime, then both code-first and database-first should be able to do so BUT then it creates a dynamic branch for your code to deal with. Meaning your code still need to know what's going to be created and totally based on dynamic query (no intellisense, no type checking at design time).

Comment: I wanted to know if add/remove column at design time using database first. i guess there is no way to do it if i'm using database first. Thanks for the reply